# celery with multiple django instances

Tags: python, django, linux, celery

I'm using several django instances, each in a virtualenv, on the same 
server. 
How can I start the celery server and make sure it is always running and 
updated? I.e. after a server restart or code update?

The /etc/init.d script and the config file assume a single Django 
installation. Do I have to use the ./manage.py celeryd command?

Regards 
Simon

Comment: How do you start your djangos ?

Comment: Check out https://github.com/mher/celery-deploy

Comment: djangos are started through runner.wsgi

Answer (score 3):

You should look at django celery. This allows you to use the `manage.py celeryd` command for each project in it's own virtualenv. You can daemonize these processes with supervisord and manage them individually.

Check out http://ask.github.com/celery/cookbook/daemonizing.html#supervisord for guidance.

Answer (score 1):

If you make changes in tasks.py for celery, then you will have to restart it once to apply changes by running command `./manage.py celeryd start` or `python manage.py celeryd start --settings=settings` for using settings.py as configuration for celery. It will not be affected by the changes in your projects until you make changes in celery configuration.